# How can I show that $z^4-2z+3$ has no zeros within the unit circle in the complex plane?

Tags: rouches-theorem

How can I show that $z^4-2z+3$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$, has no zeros within the unit circle in the complex plane? It looks like the Rouche theorem, but i still cannot do it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. :)

Comment: But we dont have |f(z)|>|g(z)| in all z with |z|=1. Do we?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out already. Thanks.

Comment: You do not need Rouche, just the triangle inequality. See the answer.

Comment: Edited because [$4z^4-2z+3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+solve+4z%5E4%E2%88%922z%2B3%3D0) does have zeroes inside the unit circle.

Comment: You are right. In this case the product of all the roots is equal ${3\over 4}.$

Comment: @JeanMarie; its from a previous edit by accident I presume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$|z^4-2z+3|\ge 3-2|z|-|z|^4.$$ Hence the equation does not admit solutions for  $|z|<1.$ In the case $|z|=1$ the equality $z^4-2z=-3$ implies $z^4=-1$ and $z=1,$ which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: How do you get your first inequality?

Comment: @RobArthan $|a+b+c|\ge |c|-|a|-|b|,$ where $a=z^4,$ $b=-2z$ and $c=3.$

Comment: And how does that inequality hold? I have looked for a proof but didn't find any.Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesJA $$|c|=|(a+b+c)+(-a)+(-b)|\le |a+b+c|+|a|+|b|$$

Answer (score 1):

A proof using Rouché's theorem.

Consider $f(z):=z^4+3$, $g(z):=−2z$.

On the disk $D_{\varepsilon}$ with center 0 and radius $1−\varepsilon$. On $\partial D_{\varepsilon}$,

$$|f(z)| \ge 2+3 \varepsilon \ \ \text{and} \ \ |g(z)| \le 2(1−\varepsilon)$$

for $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small, allowing Rouché's theorem to be applied, proving that there is no zero inside $D_{\varepsilon}$.

(thanks to Lutz Lehmann who has pointed an error of mine, now fixed).

Comment: Ok, yes, that bothersome to have missed the signs. Still, how, or better why, do get to $2+ε^4$? For $ε<\frac12$ one gets $...>2+ε+3ε^3>2+ε$

Comment: In fact, You are right, I should have written $2+3 \varepsilon + ( \varepsilon- 6\varepsilon^2 + 4 \varepsilon^3 - \varepsilon^4) > 2+3 \varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon>0$ sufficiently small. I will correct it